# Shell script - replace a string in the all the files in a directory based on file name

Tags: shell

I want to replace a constant string in multiple files based on the name of the file.

Example:
In a directory I have many files named like 'X-A01', 'X-B01', 'X-C01'.
In each file there is a string 'SS-S01'.
I want to replace string 'SS-S01' in the first file with 'X-A01', second file with 'X-B01' and third file with 'X-C01'.

Please help me how can we do it as I have hundreds of files like this and do not want to manually edit all files one by one.

Comment: Could you clarify what "member" means in this case?

Comment: Here, member means script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to **back up your files**(!) before running this command, since I have not actually tried it myself:

You could do something like:

```
for file in <DIR>/*; do sed -i "s/SS-S01/${file##*/}/" "$file"; done
```

This will loop over each file in `<DIR>` and for each loop iteration assign the file name to $file. For each file, sed will replace the first occurence of SS-S01 in that file by the file name.

Comment: Thank you @dvaergiller and Benjamin. it is working perfectly and thanks again. :)

Comment: I'm glad it was useful for you. Feel free to close the question if you are happy with the answer.